# Growth estimates for polynomials with natural coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Suppose $p(x)$ is a degree $m$ polynomial whose coefficients are natural numbers. Suppose further that we have $p(1)=n$, $p(2)\leq nm$ and $p(3)=n^2$, and assume that $m\leq \log n$. So $p$ only grows a little from $1$ to $2$ but grows a lot from $2$ to $3$. I am interested as to how well one can estimate $p(x)$ for $x\in(1,2)$.

My feeling is that, because of the positivity of the coefficients, $p$ is convex and $p$ will have to be relatively flat on $(1,2-c)$ for some sufficiently small $c$.

Comment: If $n$ is large, then the growth from $2$ to $3$ is large, indeed, but if $n$ is small, the growth too will be small. Therefore, do we know anything about $m$ and $n$ individually?

Comment: Well, I am thinking of $n$ growing, and $m$ growing much more slowly, like $m\leq \log n$.

Comment: What is the base of your $\log$? Also, for you, is $0$ a natural number?